# How to solve $y= x \cdot 2^x$ for x

Tags: logarithms

Can anyone help me solve this for $x$:

$y= x \cdot 2^x$

I know for $y= 2^x$, that
   $\log_2(y) = x$

And I can get
   $\displaystyle \frac yx = 2^x \implies \log_2 \frac yx = x $

But I can't condense to only a single $x$ in the equation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_w_function

Comment: This question has been asked so many times and answered equally many times with a link to the Lambert W-Function wiki page. How can you not have seen this before asking the question?

Answer (score 0):

ProductLog(y) is the answer. Google further to read further about its differential  equation, series expansion etc.